# How retrieve data even if not exist in a group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called mov_areas and I have SQL as you see on the bottom from the table, it is a parking system and I have a select like this

```
SELECT 
    mv_ar.name localArea, 
    COUNT(*) total, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.mov_vehicle_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CarCount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.mov_vehicle_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MotoCount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.mov_vehicle_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) VanCount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.mov_vehicle_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OniCount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.mov_vehicle_id = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CamCount
FROM 
    mov_entrys me
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         mov_entry_ean13, MAX(created_at) as MaxDate
     FROM 
         mov_entrys
     GROUP BY 
         mov_entry_ean13) entryTemp on me.mov_entry_ean13 = entryTemp.mov_entry_ean13 and me.created_at = entryTemp.MaxDate
JOIN 
    mov_areas mv_ar on mv_ar.mov_area_id = me.mov_area_id
JOIN 
    mov_locations mov_loc on mv_ar.mov_location_id = mov_loc.mov_location_id
WHERE 
    me.validated <> 'I'
    AND me.created_at >= :dataIni
    AND me.created_at <= :dataEnd
    AND mv_ar.mov_location_id = :locationId
GROUP BY 
    mv_ar.name
```

And the result is like this

```
areaid areaname total carcount motocount vancount onicount camcount
7      AB       660   600      20        20       20       0
```

It is working fine, the problem is the SQL only return areas that have data I want areas that don't have data too, how can make this work with this SQL? Like this

```
areaid areaname total carcount motocount vancount onicount camcount
    7      AB   660   600      20        20       20       0
    8      C    0     0        0         0        0        0
    9      D    0     0        0         0        0        0
```

Comment: Place `mov_areas mv_ar` as the first table in the `FROM` clause and then use `LEFT JOIN` on all the other tables instead of `INNER JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use window functions to get the most recent date.  Then, use `FILTER` for the columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT mv_ar.name as localArea, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE me.validated <> 'I' AND me.created_at >= :dataIni AND   me.created_at <= :dataEnd AND mv_ar.mov_location_id = :locationId) as total, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE me.mov_vehicle_id = 1 AND me.validated <> 'I' AND me.created_at >= :dataIni AND me.created_at <= :dataEnd AND mv_ar.mov_location_id = :locationId) as CarCount, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE me.mov_vehicle_id = 2 AND me.validated <> 'I' AND me.created_at >= :dataIni AND me.created_at <= :dataEnd AND mv_ar.mov_location_id = :locationId) as MotoCount, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE me.mov_vehicle_id = 3 AND me.validated <> 'I' AND me.created_at >= :dataIni AND   me.created_at <= :dataEnd AND mv_ar.mov_location_id = :locationId) as VanCount, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE me.mov_vehicle_id = 4 AND me.validated <> 'I' AND me.created_at >= :dataIni AND me.created_at <= :dataEnd AND mv_ar.mov_location_id = :locationId) as OniCount, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE me.mov_vehicle_id = 5 AND me.validated <> 'I' AND me.created_at >= :dataIni AND me.created_at <= :dataEnd AND mv_ar.mov_location_id = :locationId) as CamCount, 
FROM (SELECT me.*,
             MAX(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY mov_entry_ean13) as MaxDate
      FROM mov_entrys me
     ) me JOIN
     mov_areas mv_ar 
     ON mv_ar.mov_area_id = me.mov_area_id JOIN
     mov_locations mov_loc 
     ON mv_ar.mov_location_id = mov_loc.mov_location_id
WHERE me.created_at = me.MaxDate
GROUP BY mv_ar.name;
```

I might be inclined to put the filtering condition in a column in a subquery.  Depending on which condition is causing the rows to drop out, though, the approach might differ.

Comment: OMG, it works perfectly, why use FILTER? and what is OVER PARTITION that u use can u explain? really thanks

Comment: @wavrik . . . `FILTER` is standard syntax that Postgres supports for filtering of this nature.  It is quite  similar to the `SUM(CASE)` expression.  `OVER PARTITION` is for window functions.  You should learn about them.

Comment: Thank you, just one little question, in this line you put this QUERY SELECT me.*,
             MAX(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY mov_entry_ean13) as MaxDate
      FROM mov_entrys me, when I put another date that is equal to all entry like mov_entry_ean13 the query is working like before, why?

Comment: @wavrik . . . I don't understand your comment.  The expression you are referring to gets the maximum `created_at` for each `mov_entry_ean13`.